# Change sign of axis markers in tikzpicture

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I have the following MWE to generate a graph of a function, which is defined in terms of *y*. For this, I would like the *y*-axis markers to be given in positive numbers instead of negative (i.e., show the range as 0 to 10 instead of 0 to -10).  I am aware that I defined the function as a negative, but this is how the graph should look when rendered.

Is there a way to define the *y*-axis markers as positive?  Otherwise, if there's a way to define the function as positive and rotate the axes to achieve the same look, that might also be acceptable.

```
\documentclass[letterpage,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}[%
                width=0.5\textwidth,
                height=3in,
                xmin=0, xmax=140,
                ymin=-10, ymax=0,
                xlabel={Pressure $q_x$ [psf]},
                ylabel={Depth $z$ [ft]},
                every axis plot/.append style={ultra thick}
                ]
                \addplot[
                    smooth,
                    color=black,
                    variable=\y,
                    domain=-10:0,
                    samples=41
                ]
                plot ({-1000*\y/3.1415*(3*3^2+\y^2)*(3^2+\y^2)^-2},{\y});
                \addlegendentry{$q_x$}
            \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
    \caption{Lateral Stress Contour}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image: plot]

Comment: You could just add `yticklabel=\pgfmathparse{abs(\tick)}\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}` to the axis options. Or `yticklabel=\pgfmathparse{10+\tick}\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}`. I do not precisely understand what you want.

Comment: @marmot, the first option looks like it does the trick.  If you formalize that into an answer, I'll accept it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One can always apply some trickery to the labels. In this case, you may want to do

```
\documentclass[letterpage,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}[%
                width=0.5\textwidth,
                height=3in,
                xmin=0, xmax=140,
                ymin=-10, ymax=0,
                xlabel={Pressure $q_x$ [psf]},
                ylabel={Depth $z$ [ft]},
                every axis plot/.append style={ultra thick},
                yticklabel=\pgfmathparse{abs(\tick)}\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}
                ]
                \addplot[
                    smooth,
                    color=black,
                    variable=\y,
                    domain=-10:0,
                    samples=41
                ]
                plot ({-1000*\y/3.1415*(3*3^2+\y^2)*(3^2+\y^2)^-2},{\y});
                \addlegendentry{$q_x$}
            \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
    \caption{Lateral Stress Contour}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

This is, of course, trickery, and not to be confused with the "honest-to-god" coordinate transformations, which are described in section 4.21 of the pgfplots manual. If you want to read more about what I propose above, you may be interested in the examples on p. 340 of the manual.

Answer (score 2):

Besides changing the `yticklabels` you could also "reverse the y axis" together with using `-y` in the function. For details please have a look at the comments in the code.

```
% used PGFPlots v1.16
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \pgfplotsset{compat=1.3}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[%
        width=0.5\textwidth,
        height=3in,
        xmin=0,
        xmax=140,
        ymin=0,             % <-- changed
        ymax=10,            % <-- changed
        xlabel={Pressure $q_x$ [psf]},
        ylabel={Depth $z$ [ft]},
        every axis plot/.append style={ultra thick},
        y dir=reverse,      % <-- added
    ]
        \addplot[
            smooth,
            color=black,
            variable=\y,
            domain=-10:0,
            samples=41
        ] (
            -1000 * \y / 3.1415 * (3*3^2 + \y^2) * (3^2 + \y^2)^-2,
            -\y             % <-- added minus sign
        );
        \addlegendentry{$q_x$}
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]